# facebook redirect_uri not redirecting to right url, but to https://apps.facebook.com/_APP_ID

Tags: facebook, redirect, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

Here is the flow,

- 1.user opens a page tab, with an application
- 1.1 the app detects if the user has authorized the app do access his personal data
- 1.1.1 if not, make authurl and redirect the user to get permission
- 1.1.2 he is authorized, ok continue with execution

.
.

i have a problem with step 1.1.1, here is the function code i call if the user has not authorized the app

```
function askForPermission(app_data) {
var oauth_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
oauth_url += '?client_id=' + app_id;
oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(app_url + '&app_data=' + app_data);
oauth_url += '&scope=user_about_me';
window.top.location = oauth_url;
```

}

Here everything goes ok, but when the user clicks ok in the auth dialog, i get redirected to 
APP_ID/#*=*">https://apps.facebook.com/**APP_ID**/#*=* , and not to the page tab url i have specified in the redirect_uri.
I don't get why, i have googled for hours without result. Has anyone had a similar problem?How did he fix it?

Comment: What value is in app_url?

Comment: the url of the page tab, the strange thing is that now it does redirect normal.

Comment: Did you find any answers? I'm facing same issue.